# NSXMLParser divides string with unicode characters

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsxmlparser

I am using NSXMLParser to get the following string(sqrt(2 x)^(7/6)×(7/6)/(4/9)) from the following xml code:

```
 <pod title='Input'
     scanner='Identity'
     id='Input'
     position='100'
     error='false'
     numsubpods='1'>
  <subpod title=''>
   <plaintext>sqrt(2 x)^(7/6)×(7/6)/(4/9)</plaintext>
  </subpod>
 </pod>
```

But the output string is being divided into two separate strings by the foundCharacters function which returns the following result (using NSLog):

> 2011-11-11 18:29:46.005 Wolfram API-test[35959:f803] sqrt(2 x)^(7/6)
>   2011-11-11 18:29:46.005 Wolfram API-test[35959:f803] ×(7/6)/(4/9)

The code for the parsing looks like this:

```
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *) parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if (elementFound) {
        [string canBeConvertedToEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"%@", string);
    }
```

}

So my question is why the output string is being divided into two separate strings?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it's being divided in this case, but in general you shouldn't expect the data you get from `-parser:foundCharacters:` to all be returned at once. Instead, you should accumulate the characters you get from that method in a string. You can then do something when your parser delegate is notified that the end tag has been received in `-parser:didEndElement:...`

The unicode character may or may not be the reason that your data was split up, but whether it was or wasn't shouldn't matter to your code.

Comment: That is a good idea but the problem with it is that i have to use -parser:didStartElement ... because I need to access the attributes dictionary which I can get from -parser:didStartElement using attributes:(NSDictionary *) attributeDict but I can not do that with -parser:didEndElemet

Comment: You should use all 3 methods: didStartElement, foundCharacters, and didEndElement. You can store the data as necessary during the first two, but if you want the entire element you can't act on that data until didEndElement. This is just how NSXMLParser works. If it's a problem, you might want to take a different approach to parsing your XML, such as TouchXML.